# How to extract elements of NSArray and convert them(parseInt) to integer values?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nsarray

I have a string which is a 13 digit number. I need to separate all the digits and find the sum of the individual digits. How can I do that?

I converted the string to NSArray like this :

```
NSArray *arrStrDigits = [str13DigitNumber componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
```

now I want to run a loop and get something like arrStrDigits[i]

I am new to Objective C :(. Please help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the individual digits like this:

```
unichar digitChar = [str13DigitNumber characterAtIndex: someIndex];
// Should put in some validation that you have a digit here
int digit = digitChar - '0';
```

That just needs to go in a loop where you iterate `someIndex` from 0 to `[str13DigitNumber length]`

Comment: What does this line do?  int digit = digitChar - '0';

Comment: @user523234: `digitChar` is a UTF-16 character.  The decimal numbers are represented by the characters between 48 (represents 0) and 57 (represents 9).  So `digitChar - '0'` subtracts the character code for 0 (i.e. 48) from the character code you have leaving you with the numerical value of the digit.  e.g. '4' is represented by character 52, `'4' - '0' == 52 - 48 == 4`

Comment: This assumes that all of the characters are ASCII digits (between `'0'` and `'9'`). Any characters outside of that range, including both other numbers (there are many sets of numeric characters in Unicode) and non-numbers, will give nonsensical results.

Comment: @Peter Hosey:  it'll work for 99.99% of input and there is a comment line that says "do some validation"

Answer (score 2):

```
int total=0; 
for(NSString *numberInString in arrStrDigits)
{ 
    total+=[numberInString intValue];
}
```

**Note:** I am assuming you have int's in each position of your array.

**Note 1:** This answer is only related to what you ask (run a loop, nothing else).